# D3js first tick label is missing

Tags: d3.js, axis, axis-labels

I don't understand why the first label (2000) is missing. I compared it to many examples without finding why.

[image: axis]

```
    let xAxisScale = d3
        .scaleTime()
        .domain([min, max]) // 2000, 2013
        .range([0, width]);

        xAxis = d3
        .axisBottom()
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%Y'))
        .tickPadding(5)
        .ticks(d3.timeYear)
        .scale(xAxisScale);

        gx = innerSpace
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(xAxis);
```

Do you see any errors ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next to your nice answer I tried different ways to get a datetime without utc / gmt problems but didn't find a nice solution of dealing with it for all web explorer without using library.

The best solution I find is to use the library momentjs because momentjs will nicely handle the timezone :

```
const minMoment = moment(`01/01/${minDate}`, 'DD/MM/YYYY', true);
const maxMoment = moment(`01/01/${maxDate}`, 'DD/MM/YYYY', true);

this.xAxisScale = d3
    .scaleTime()
    .domain([minMoment.toDate(), maxMoment.toDate()])
    .range([0, width]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem may be due to small variations in `min` date. It depends on the way you construct `min` date.

For example, `new Date('2000-01-01')` does not include year 2000 if your time zone is >0. You can write `new Date('2000-01-01T00:00:00Z')` to use UTC.

Also, if you use `new Date(YYYY, MM, DD)`, you should take into account, that month starts from zero, while day starts from one.

Read about correct way of dealing with that problem here: http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/9671241